# IIS Gives 404 Error to existing files coz of incorrect physical path

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I have deployed a new ASP .NET website to a folder named D:/mywebsite

I have configured the IIS to publish this website and server pages and code work fine.

Now my issue is, "some" of the static files (like images, CSS, or JavaScript) give error 404 while other static files do not. This is strange as all of these static files belong to the same subfolder.

When I investigated the issue a little bit, I found that IIS is trying to retrieve (404 Not Found) files from C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\img instead of the website folder D:\mywebsite\assets\img . The more strange is that only happening to some files and some are not.

So why the IIS is convinced that specific files are belonging to default wwwroot folder not the website root folder.

When I copied the 404 files into the wwwroot, error disappeared and files retrieved successfully. But this is not a solution this is a stupid work around.

I had checked the security and there is no issue there. I checked also the file naming and no issue as well.

I'm using IIS 7.5 with integrated mode.

Your support is highly appreciated.